# how concat each element from two lists to a new one?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have to list one with Cds and other with names

```
final List<String> Cds = listSiccdsByRegion.stream().map(sic -> (String)sic.get(0)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Output :0 1 2 3

```
final List<String> names = listSiccdsByRegion.stream().map(sic -> (String)sic.get(1)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Output : Jhon doe data dummy

Is there is a way to convince both element and return a list joining like this?

Cds  Names 
0 Jhon
1 Doe
2 Dummy
3 Data

Comment: one good old `for` loop for the win (its trivial to use the length which is supposed to be the same here) ... not everything has to be done with fancy streams.

Comment: What is the type of listSiccdsByRegion? The question is not clear.

Comment: Why not just concat `sic.get(0)` and `sic.get(1)`, e.g. `.map(sic -> sic.get(0) + " " + sic.get(1))`? Note that you don't have _two_ lists, you actually have _one_ collection `listSiccdsByRegion` that already contains the necessary data - just map that to whatever format you need.

Comment: yeah, that would even be more trivial if you don't need both generated list for some other task

Comment: @AKSW well in that case he'd still be able to generate those lists as well. I'd not suggest creating 2 lists from 1 source and then rejoining them - that's bound to get more complicated and error prone than just directly working with the source.

Comment: what is the type of `sic`?

Comment: @Naman its String too .. but dont worry its already resolved

Comment: I wonder how do you do a `sic.get(0)` if its `String`? Additionally, that cast that you are performing. Certainly the picture you're looking at is not the source of the problem.

Comment: @Naman I think it should be a `List<String>`

Comment: @RavindraRanwala We can speculate, but then you would agree that the explicit cast wouldn't be required. Anyway, hope the OP has the answer with the type already resolved.

Comment: @Naman Yeah, I was about to add a comment asking him to remove the unnecessary cast. But since the problem is solved and the existing code is no longer needed, I thought of omitting that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the assumption that `listSiccdsByRegion` is of type `List<List<String>>` you may solve it as shown below. The trick here is that you can use the `map` operator to convert it into the required format.

```
List<String> result = listSiccdsByRegion.stream()
    .map(sic -> sic.get(0) + " " + sic.get(1))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: ... if we assume that both lists won't be needed for some other task which we don't know